# AngularJS Scope with GMaps

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm having a little trouble when trying to modify an Angular Model from a GMaps event, heres is the code:

```
function CtrlGMap($scope) {

var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-54.798112, -68.303375),
    zoom: 11,
    //disableDefaultUI: true,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
};

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapCanvas'), mapOptions);

google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function(e) {
    lat = e.latLng.lat();
    lng = e.latLng.lng();

    $scope.lat = lat;
)};
```

**HTML:**

```
<body ng-controller="CtrlGMap">

<div id="mapCanvas"></div>

<form role="form" style="width: 30%; margin:0 auto;">

    <div class="form-inline">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="sr-only" for="lat">Latitud</label>
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon">Lat</span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lat" ng-model="lat" disabled>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

The thing is that I have no access to $scope from inside the GMap event ... why is that?

Comment: Might help if you could elaborate on what you mean by "I have no access to $scope from inside the GMap event".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to call $scope.apply() if you are changing the scope outside the realm of angularjs.

So like this:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function(e) {
    lat = e.latLng.lat();
    lng = e.latLng.lng();

    $scope.lat = lat;
    // Let angularjs know.
    $scope.$apply();
)};
```

Comment: Thanks it helped. But the actual method is .$apply with the dollar sign!